# Where are col and window methods defined in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I found this construct.

```
purchaseByCustomerPerHour = streamingDataFrame\
.selectExpr(
"CustomerId",
"(UnitPrice * Quantity) as total_cost",
"InvoiceDate")\
.groupBy(
col("CustomerId"), window(col("InvoiceDate"), "1 day"))\
.sum("total_cost")
```

Where are `col` and `window` methods defined? I couldn't find them in Spark's API documentation.

Answer (score -2):

found it. Its at https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$

I should I noticed the `import` keyword used in the same code